# C# how to add resource

Tags: c#, resources

I'm trying to add an EXE file in Resources to Form1.resx. I did everything as it is written on MSDN but I can't access resource using `Properties.Resources.resname`, resname - resource name. Help, please.

Comment: so, do you get resource not found error?

Comment: No, if you type `Properties.Resources.`, you'll see all accessible fields. If I add image through picturebox designer, it will appear in `Properties.Resources.` as field. But if I add any file through resource editor it will not appear in field list.